# how to filter products in GraphQL based on custom type array

Tags: magento2.3.2, graphql

I'm trying to add some extra filterable information in the graphql `products` Query related to the categories.

More specifically I want to add the slug and the category id of all associated product categories.

I've created my resolver

```
class CategorySlug implements ResolverInterface
{
    private $categoryRepository;

    public function __construct(CategoryRepositoryInterface $categoryRepository)
    {
        $this->categoryRepository = $categoryRepository;
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function resolve(
        Field       $field,
                    $context,
        ResolveInfo $info,
        array       $value = null,
        array       $args = null
    )
    {
        if (!isset($value['model'])) {
            throw new LocalizedException(__('"model" value should be specified'));
        }

        /* @var $product Product */
        $product = $value['model'];
        $categoryIds = $product->getCategoryIds();
        $slugs = [];
        foreach($categoryIds as $categoryId){
            $category = $this->categoryRepository->get($categoryId);
            $slugs[] = ['slug' => $category->getUrlKey(), 'id' => $category->getId()];
        }
        return $slugs;

    }
}
```

And I've extended my schema.graphqsl file to do this

```
# noinspection GraphQLUnresolvedReference

interface ProductInterface @typeResolver(class: "Magento\\CatalogGraphQl\\Model\\ProductInterfaceTypeResolverComposite") @doc(description: "The ProductInterface contains attributes that are common to all types of products. Note that descriptions may not be available for custom and EAV attributes.") {
    brand: Int @doc(description: "Brand Name based on manufacturer attribute") @resolver(class: "Vendor\\GraphQlExtend\\Model\\Resolver\\Product\\Brand")
    category_slugs: [CategorySlug] @doc(description: "Search based on category slug") @resolver(class: "Vendor\\GraphQlExtend\\Model\\Resolver\\Product\\CategorySlug")
}

input BrandInput @doc(description:"Comment for FilterTypeInput") {
    eq: Int @doc(description:"Equal")
    in: [Int]
    neq: Int
    notnull: String
    null: String
    nin: [Int]
}

input CategorySlugInput {
    eq: String
}

input ProductFilterInput {
    brand: BrandInput @doc(description: "Brand ID")
    category_slugs: CategorySlugInput @doc(description: "Category slug")
}

type Query {
    filteredCustomerOrders(
        filter: FilteredCustomerOrdersFilterInput,
        pageSize: Int = 20,
        currentPage: Int = 1
    ): FilteredCustomerOrdersData
    @resolver(class: "Vendor\\GraphQlExtend\\Model\\Resolver\\Customer\\Orders\\FilteredCustomerOrders")
    @cache(cacheable: false)
}

type FilteredCustomerOrdersData {
    totalCount: Int
    items: [CustomerOrder]
}

input FilteredCustomerOrdersFilterInput {
    status: FilterTypeInput
}

type CategoryTree implements CategoryInterface{
    thumbnail_url: String @resolver(class: "Vendor\\GraphQlExtend\\Model\\Resolver\\Category\\ThumbnailResolver")
}

type CategorySlug {
    id: Int
    slug: String
}
```

Now my Query will yield the correct field data like this

```
{
    products(
        filter: {
        }
        pageSize: 2
    ) 
    {
        total_count,
        items
        {
            id,
            category_slugs
            {   
                id,
                slug
            }
        } 
    }
}
```

Result

```
{
    "data": {
        "products": {
            "total_count": 1544,
            "items": [
                {
                    "id": 7690,
                    "category_slugs": [
                        {
                            "id": 62,
                            "slug": "straps-and-stands"
                        },
                        {
                            "id": 80,
                            "slug": "all-products"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "id": 8794,
                    "category_slugs": [
                        {
                            "id": 24,
                            "slug": "gaming-ar"
                        },
                        {
                            "id": 80,
                            "slug": "all-products"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

The problem I'm facing is trying to filter the results based on the slug.

For example to show only the results where `"slug": "gaming-ar"`

Because my field category_slugs is an array I can't really filter it properly.

A query like this

```
{
    products(
        filter: {
            category_slugs: {
                eq: "accessories"                
            }
        }
        pageSize: 2
    ) 
    {
        total_count,
        items
        {
            id,
            category_slugs
            {   
                id,
                slug
            }
        } 
    }
}
```

Yields an error

```
{
    "errors": [
        {
            "debugMessage": "The \"category_slugs\" attribute name is invalid. Reset the name and try again.",
            "message": "Internal server error",
            "category": "internal",
            "locations": [
                {
                    "line": 2,
                    "column": 5
                }
            ],
            "path": [
                "products"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "data": {
        "products": null
    }
}
```

Any ideas how to modify my graphql schema to support a query like that?

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge,
If you need to have a product filter you should create the product attribute and set any of the below two configuration

- Set the Use in Layered Navigation field to Filterable (with results) or Filterable (no results).
- Set the Use in Search and Visible in Advanced Search fields to Yes.

Only then magento will index the attribute’s contents and making the data available for search.

Comment: Thank you for the answer but it's a bit off topic. I've already created attributes that are filterable to add them with a Custom Resolver but the goal here isn't just to compare a single attribute. It's to link Custom Type Arrays to the product and filter on the Arrays themselves based on their respective fields.

Answer (score 0):

did you find a solution to it? I am facing a similar problem right now

Comment: Unfortunately no, I had to go the inverse way and filter a category by url_key and then get the children products for it instead, but this meant extra queries :(